# How can i create MySqlCommand when i put my MySqlConnection in other class and call it from my other form

Tags: c#, mysql, class, visual-studio-2013

Good Programmers. Can anyone help me in c#. How can i call this class from my other form whenever i want to insert or execute any queries.

Here is my Class named DBConnection:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    class DBConnector
    {
        private MySqlConnection con;
        private String server;
        private String db;
        private String uid;
        private String password;

        public DBConnector()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            server = "localhost";
            db = "test";
            uid = "root";
            password = "";
            String connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
            db + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

            con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }

        public void DatabaseConnector()
        {
            server = "localhost";
            db = "test";
            uid = "root";
            password = "";
            String connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
            db + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

            con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }
        public void OpenCon()
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        public void CloseCon()
        {
            con.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my Form Button Class whenever i press the button . Then it will query. My Problem is how can i call the `con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);` to create MySqlCommand. Please help. i was being confused.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class FrmAdd : Form 
    {

        public FrmAdd()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FrmAdd_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var mycon = new DBConnector();

            try
            {
                mycon.OpenCon();
                MessageBox.Show("Well done!");
            }
            catch (MySqlException  ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You failed!" + ex.Message);
            }


            string query = "INSERT INTO info values (1,'John','Mac','P',21)";



        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the `MySqlConnection` object in another class, you need to mark the `DbConnector` class as `internal` or `public`, i.e. it should become:

```
public class DbConnector{
    ...
}
```

You also need to set the access modifier on the property itself and add a getter like so:

```
public MySqlConnection con { get; }
```

Then, in `FrmAdd` after you instantiate `DbConnector` you can use the database object like `mycon.con.SomeMethod()`.

Also, why do you have two methods `DatabaseConnector()` and `Initialize()` if they do the same thing?